# Updating a dictionary of trajectories after a step has been made

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I use a dictionary to save possible trajectories in a game. A "trajectory" is defined as a list of numbers separated by `'_'`, for example `'3_7_2_5'` is a trajectory of 4 steps. The dictionary is needed because to each trajectory I assign a value, whose meaning does not matter for the purpose of my question. I save the trajectories in separated dictionaries if they have different numbers of steps.

I want to update the dictionary in such a way that only the trajectories starting from `'1'` are preserved. Moreover, I want to remove the `'1'` from the name, since I don't need to keep listing a step that has already been made.

This is how I do it:

```
# here I create the initial dictionaries 

pts=[{},{},{}]

for j in range(20):
    k=random.choice(range(3))
    path=str(k)
    for d in range(len(pts)):
        k=random.choice(range(4))       
        pts[d][path]=k
        path+='_'+str(k)

print 'initial dictionaries =',pts

# here I make the update


ind=1
new_pts=[{},{},{}]
path=str(ind)
for d in range(len(pts)-1):
    for path in pts[d+1]:
        if path[:len(str(ind))]==str(ind):
            new_pts[d][path[len(str(ind))+1:]]=pts[d+1][path]


pts=new_pts

print 'updated dictionaries =',pts
```

Now, it seems to me that my algorithm is not very efficient. For updating the dictionary I am doing a `for` loop over all keys, even though most of them are going to be discarded.
Is there a better, faster way to do this ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the update? For example with `{'2_2': 1, '1_3': 2, '1_0': 2, '0_0': 3, '0_3': 1, '1_1': 0, '2_3': 0, '0_1': 1}` how it will change?

Comment: @MrNobody33 If the step is `'1'`, it must become `{'3': 2,'0':2,'1':0}` . So the two steps trajectories you wrote become the new one step trajectories in the updated dictionary, but we keep only those that were starting with `1`.

Comment: @MrNobody33 In your example, `'2_2':1` for example will be discarded, because I am not interested in trajectories that do not start by `1`. `'1_3': 2` , on the other hand, will become `'3':2`, because I preserve it and remove the initial step.

Comment: Ok, it's cleaner now :). But, why `{'2': 3, '1': 1, '0': 0}` changes to `{'3': 1, '0': 2, '1': 1}`?, I know that `1:1` is preserved but, the others?

Comment: Sorry, my notation is misleading. The values relative to a trajectory does not matter. It just matters that the first element of their name is `1`.

Comment: @MrNobody33 `'1_3':2` is preserved because `'1_3'` starts with `'1'`, it doesn't matter what the relative value is (`2` in this case, but it's irrelevant. Could be `anything`).

Comment: For advice on working code, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: If the values starting with '1' (or the number of choice) can be anywhere in the array, somehow it will have to check each key. If you want, I've done a version where the update is done using string comprehension, which may be faster

Comment: Yeah yeah, I got that, but I get this `{'2': 3, '1': 1, '0': 0}` as your first dictionary and the updated dicionary becomes like this: `{'3': 1, '0': 2, '1': 1}`. The item 1:1 it's keep it, as you said, but the others items, how is its change?

Comment: @MrNobody33 The single step trajectories are all removed, because I already know what the step will be (`1`). So what used to be the two step trajectories will become the new single step trajectories, the initial three steps tr. the new two steps and so on.

Comment: @MrNobody33 in other words, the first element in the old list `pts` will always be completely discarded. The second element will be used to create the first element of the new list and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with regex:

```
import re
import random
pts=[{},{},{}]

for j in range(20):
    k=random.choice(range(3))
    path=str(k)
    for d in range(len(pts)):
        k=random.choice(range(4))       
        pts[d][path]=k
        path+='_'+str(k)

print ('initial dictionaries =',pts)

# here I make the update

new_pts= [{str(k)[2:]:dc[k] for k in list(re.findall('(?:^|\s)(1_\w+)',', '.join(dc.keys())))} for dc in pts]

pts=new_pts

print ('updated dictionaries =',pts)
```

Output:

```
initial dictionaries = [{'1': 2, '0': 2, '2': 0}, {'1_1': 2, '0_3': 0, '2_2': 3, '1_3': 0, '0_0': 3, '2_1': 1, '2_3': 3, '1_0': 0, '1_2': 0, '2_0': 1, '0_2': 2}, {'1_1_0': 2, '0_3_2': 0, '1_1_2': 1, '1_1_1': 2, '2_2_3': 0, '1_1_3': 3, '1_3_0': 0, '0_3_0': 2, '0_0_2': 2, '2_1_1': 3, '0_0_3': 0, '2_3_3': 1, '1_0_0': 3, '1_2_2': 2, '1_2_0': 2, '2_0_1': 0, '0_2_2': 2}]


updated dictionaries = [{}, {'1': 2, '3': 0, '0': 0, '2': 0}, {'1_0': 2, '1_2': 1, '1_1': 2, '1_3': 3, '3_0': 0, '0_0': 3, '2_2': 2, '2_0': 2}]
```

**Edit:**
If you condition isn't that starts with `'1_'`, instead it starts with a given string:

```
dc={'first_second_third':50, 'second_first':25,'first_second_fourth':2000,'first_zero_third':'hello',}
my_string='first_'
new_pts= {str(k)[len(my_string):]:dc[k] for k in list(re.findall('(?:^|\s)({0}\w+)'.format(my_string),', '.join(dc.keys())))}
print(new_pts)
```

Output:

```
dc
{'first_second_third': 50, 'second_first': 25, 'first_second_fourth': 2000, 'first_zero_third': 'hello'}

new_pts
{'second_third': 50, 'second_fourth': 2000, 'zero_third': 'hello'}
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to generalize in case I have the string of a given index `ind` rather than `'1'` specifically? Should I use something like `%s_... %ind` ?

Comment: You mean, instead of find all the values that start with `1_`, find all the values that start with some `ind` given?

Comment: yes, I see that you wrote `_1` explicitly in your code. How does it work for a generic string `my_string` . I have nver used `re` . 
BTW is this method faster than using the `for` loop over all keys of the dictionary?

Comment: @3sm1r, I just edited the answer to a general key. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating your code in order to use a list comprehension might be faster, so you can try to do this:

```
# here I make the update

ind = "1_"
new_pts = []

for path in pts[1:]:
    d = dict([(key[len(ind):], value) for key, value in path.items() if key.startswith(ind)])
    new_pts.append(d)

pts = new_pts
```

Still, the code will have to check for every item, one way or another.